# Selecting records that have low numbers consecutively

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table as following (using bigquery):

| id | year | month | day | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2020 | 11 | 30 | 4 |
| 111 | 2020 | 12 | 01 | 4 |
| 112 | 2020 | 11 | 30 | 5 |
| 113 | 2020 | 11 | 30 | 5 |

Is there a way in which I can select ids that have ratings that are consecutively (two or more consecutive records) low (low as in both records' ratings less than 4.5)?

For example, my desired output is:

| id | year | month | day | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2020 | 11 | 30 | 4 |
| 111 | 2020 | 12 | 01 | 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *all* rows, then you need to look at both the previous rating and the next rating:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LAG(rating) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year, month, day ASC) AS prev_rating,
             LEAD(rating) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year, month, day ASC) AS next_rating,
      FROM dataset.table t
     ) t
WHERE (rating < 4.5 and prev_rating < 4.5) OR
      (rating < 4.5 and next_rating < 4.5)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think this works better. It returns all rows, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select * except(grp, seq_len)
from (
  select *, sum(1) over(partition by grp) seq_len
  from (
    select *,
      countif(rating >= 4.5) over(partition by id order by year, month, day) grp
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
  where rating < 4.5 
)
where seq_len > 1
```